# How to connect Hive and Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark

I am not able to connect hive meta store from spark SQL. I have created Hive-Context in spark shell.what other changes required in Hive?

Answer (score 0):

You need to link hive-site.xml with spark conf or copy hive-site.xml into spark conf directory. Spark is not able to find your hive metastore (derby database which is by default), so for that we have to link hive-conf to spark conf direcrtory.

Finally, to connect Spark SQL to an existing Hive installation, you must copy your hive-site.xml file to Spark’s configuration directory ($SPARK_HOME/conf). If you don’t have an existing Hive installation, Spark SQL will still run.

Sudo to root user and then copy hive-site to spark conf directory.

sudo -u root 
cp /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml /etc/spark/conf